# virtual machine replication between two separated Hyper-v clusters

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, cluster, replication

I have two identical hyper-v cluster configurations.

Here is the configuration: 2 hyper-v servers in cluster with shared via fiber channel storage.

There is a 10 Gbit ethernet between these clusers. The question is, how can i make virtual machine replication (mirroring) between these two clusters?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this post, explaining how to configure separate clusters to achieve your goal : http://www.petri.co.il/use-hyper-v-replica-broker-prepare-host-clusters.htm

Briefly, you will have to configure a new role to your clusters : Replica Broker.

Once configured, you should be able to replicate VM with the Replication wizard.

Hope this helps,

Regards.